# Method to call one string in a list repeatedly. [Python]

Tags: python

I would like to create a class that initiates a list of items, and whenever I call the method `next()` it will show a different output.

Suppose the list is [1,2,3]
when I call `next()`
the code should return 1
and when I call it again it should return 2
and after the list has exhausted it should repeat 1 again.

Answer (score 3):

[`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) from built-in module `itertools` can do it, consider following example:

```
import itertools
cyc = itertools.cycle([1,2,3])
print(next(cyc))
print(next(cyc))
print(next(cyc))
print(next(cyc))
print(next(cyc))
print(next(cyc))
```

output:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Edit: If you must avoid `import` AT ANY PRICE then you might do:

```
def cycle(lst):
    while True:
        yield lst[0]
        lst.append(lst.pop(0))
```

but beware that `list` you feed into it is altered during cycling, that is

```
lst_1 = [1,2,3]
cyc = cycle(lst_1)
next(cyc)
next(cyc)
print(lst_1)
```

output:

```
[2, 3, 1]
```

which is different behavior than in case of `itertools.cycle`.

Comment: Thank you sincerely for the solution! but I'd like to know some elementary solution for this question, instead of using advance built-in modules! It would be greatly appreciated